# Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'User' && firebase is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using TypeScript in my React application and I have an error *"Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'User'"* when getting an `accessToken` of user

My handler function in component:

```js
const handleRegister = (email: string, password: string) => {
  const auth = getAuth();

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(({user}) => {
      dispatch(setUser({
        email: user.email,
        token: user.accessToken,
        id: user.uid
      }));
    });
}
```

after searching for a solution to this problem, I did this

```js
token: (user as unknown as OAuthCredential).accessToken,
```

and IDE automatically added the following imports

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat";
import OAuthCredential = firebase.auth.OAuthCredential;
```

But after that I get an error in the console *"Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined"*.
I feel stupid but I don't understand how to solve it

Comment: The `accessToken` property is indeed present in the response but is missing from the `User` interface and also the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user). It might be best to post an issue on [Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) as well.

Answer (score 0):

do this see what results you get, i think you need result.user.accessToken but im not sure

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
   .then((result: any) => {
     // Signed in 
     console.log(result)
     // ...
})
```

Comment: through `console.log()` I see that the user has property **accessToken**

Comment: add `(result: any)` instead

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but you can use something like below.

```
const handleRegister = (email: string, password: string) => {
  const auth = getAuth();

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(({user}) => {
     user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {
       // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        dispatch(setUser({
          email: user.email,
          token: idToken,
          id: user.uid
        }));
       // ...
     }).catch(function(error) {
       // Handle error
     });
      
    });
}
```